# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

Tags: mysql, django, docker, docker-compose, containers

I had created a django application and using mysql as db back-end. Everything was working fine on my local machine so i tried to dockerize this application. And i have written code mentioned below to dockerize my application.

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'cool_db'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'hello@123*'
    container_name: mysql01
    restart: always
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: django01
    command: bash -c "python3 manage.py makemigrations && python3 manage.py migrate && python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes: 
    - my-vol:/src
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - mysql
    depends_on: 
      - mysql
    expose:
      - "8000"
    restart: always

volumes: 
  my-vol:
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:latest

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /src 
WORKDIR /src/

COPY ./requirements.txt /src/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /src/requirements.txt

COPY . /src/

EXPOSE 8000
```

#### requirements.txt

```
autopep8==1.5.2
boto3==1.14.7
celery==3.1.24
channels==2.4.0
channels-redis==2.4.2
configparser==5.0.0
django==3.0.3
djangorestframework==3.11.0
mysqlclient==1.4.6
pre-commit==2.2.0
redis==2.10.6
requests==2.23.0
WhiteNoise==5.1.0
```

#### settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": config.get("database", "DATABASE_ENGINE"),
        "NAME": config.get("database", "DATABASE_NAME"),
        "USER": config.get("database", "DATABASE_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": config.get("database", "DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": config.get("database", "DATABASE_HOST"),
        "PORT": config.get("database", "DATABASE_PORT"),
    }
}
```

#### config.cfg

```
[database]
DATABASE_USER: root
DATABASE_PASSWORD: hello@123
DATABASE_HOST: mysql
DATABASE_PORT: 3306
DATABASE_ENGINE: django.db.backends.mysql
DATABASE_NAME: cool_db
```

But when i run this code using `sudo docker-compose up` then my django service unable to connect with mysql service and raise this error **django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")**
Although mysql was also running on my system i verified it using `sudo docker ps`. It listed 2 container was running, Mysql container was running without any problem, But django container due to the error mentioned restarts again and again with the same error.

Comment: can you connect to your db outside the django container
Try to connect to it using an alpine or ubuntu container

Comment: Yes, first i run docker container using `sudo docker-compose up -d` and then i run `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p` and then entered password for mysql it connect to mysql container

Comment: That looks like the config file you show isn't being read.  You have a lot of unnecessary settings in your `docker-compose.yml` file; among those, the `volumes:` you have tell Docker to ignore any changes in your code or configuration.  Does deleting `volumes:` help here at all?

Comment: No deleting volume does not helped

Comment: I get same error. Did u solution problem?